# How to kill listed inhibitors for proper working of suspend on Laptop lid close

Tags: gnome, suspend, laptop, systemd, debian

I recently noticed that my laptop can't be suspended via closing its lid. Suspend when laptop lid is closed Switch is turned ON in settings.

I have the following settings set in the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Output:

```
[Login]  
InhibitDelayMaxSec=5  
HandleSuspendKey=suspend  
HandleLidSwitch=suspend  
HandleLidSwitchDocked=suspend
```

I tried to change `HandleLidSwitch=` to something else: poweroff, suspend, hibernate -- none of them work.

After doing some research on the internet, I figured out that 4 programs have taken over the lid-switch handling. It appears as a "handle-lid-switch" inhibitor in the list.

```
$ systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block
```

Output:

```
WHO        UID USER       PID  COMM           WHAT                              
root       0   root       8474 gsd-power      handle-lid-switch                 
root       0   root       8520 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-ke
Debian-gdm 138 Debian-gdm 8162 gsd-power      handle-lid-switch                 
Debian-gdm 138 Debian-gdm 8176 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-ke

4 inhibitors listed.
```

I tried to kill these processes but it results in a system crash because these are the system processes.

Comment: Could this be the same issue as [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196871/gnome-supend-on-laptop-lid-close-no-longer-works-since-19-10-upgrade)? Unfortunately, the `systemd-inhibit --list` is cropped on the right side. So the "Why" column is not visible. Could you copy the full output?